# How to retrieve a TextBox from DetailsView - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I have a DetailsView Control, inside as a template a TextBox.
I need to find out the value for a TextBox when Inserting data Event handler-, _ItemInserting.

The script does not work. Ant ideas?? Thanks

-------------------- WEB FORM

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Profile" SortExpression="ContentAuthor">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="uxContentAuthorDisplayer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContentAuthor") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="uxContentAuthorInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContentAuthor") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

-------------------- CODE BEHIND

```
          protected void uxInsertAuthor_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
        {
            //// Find control on page
            TextBox myAuthorProfile = (TextBox)uxInsertAuthorInput.FindControl("uxContentAuthorDisplayer");
            // Set a default value in Data Base if field has been left empty (DB field NOT NULL)           
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myAuthorProfile.Text))
            {
                string myAllert = "Field is NULL";
            }
            else
            {
                string myAllet = "Field is NOT NULL";
            }          
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `FindControl` method of your `TemplateField` container control (the DetailsView). For example, if your DetailsView is named "MyControl" try

```
//// Find control on page
TextBox myAuthorProfile = (TextBox)MyControl.FindControl("uxContentAuthorInput");
```

### Please Note

**You are using the ID of the Label control in your FindControl method and you are trying to cast it to a TextBox.**

Comment: I did, but does not work, could you please have a quick look at my code? thnaks

Comment: @GibboK: the code is as before. Anyway I have realized that you're using the `uxContentAuthorDisplayer` in the FindControl method, which is the ID of the label not the one of the TextBox. You should use `uxContentAuthorInput` instead.

Comment: you are right I made a mistake before. Mny thanks for your help :-) bye

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to get the value from the [`DetailsViewInsertEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsviewinserteventargs.aspx). It has a property called `Values` which is a dictionary with all the bound values that will go into the database from the DetailsView. So you could do the following instead:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Values("ContentAuthor")))
{
  string myAlert = "Field is NULL";
}
else
{
  string myAlert = "Field is NOT NULL";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want to check the value of the `TextBox` when the data is put into the `DetailsView`. The `ItemInserting` event is not the one you're looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/keezbt7k.aspx

I'd say `ItemCreated` is the one you're looking for.